# Hide entire browser toolbar on demand in safari iOS 16 w/ javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari

I'm attempting to produce kind of like a Fullscreen experience while on landscape mode but nothing seems to work so far. I got a video that fakes going fullscreen mode as I have my own controls, unfortunately iOS doesn't support entering fullscreen on nothing except HTML5 `<video>` tags, so since I'm forced to use Fullscreen API and can't control those native buttons' visibility while on fullscreen state, I need to do something else which is faking it.

I want to produce the same effect as when going to `"Aa button" on Search Bar` > `Hide Toolbar`. It collapses everything and shows almost the entire screen space.

I tried going the CSS way or the `window.scrollTo(0, 1)` trick. Not working in my case as I have a fixed non-scrollable container holding the video and occupying the entire screen.

Also tried with this and many other codepens & jsfiddles on my Safari, none worked.

```
/*!
Intelligent auto-scrolling to hide the mobile device address bar
Optic Swerve, opticswerve.com
Documented at http://menacingcloud.com/?c=iPhoneAddressBar
*/

var bodyTag;
var executionTime = new Date().getTime(); // JavaScript execution time

// Document ready
//----------------
documentReady(function() {
    // Don't hide address bar after a distracting amount of time
    var readyTime = new Date().getTime()
    if((readyTime - executionTime) < 3000) hideAddressBar(true);

});

// Run specified function when document is ready (HTML5)
//------------------------------------------------------
function documentReady(readyFunction) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', arguments.callee, false);
        readyFunction();

    }, false);

}

// Hide address bar on devices like the iPhone
//---------------------------------------------
function hideAddressBar(bPad) {
    // Big screen. Fixed chrome likely.
    if(screen.width > 980 || screen.height > 980) return;

    // Standalone (full screen webapp) mode
    if(window.navigator.standalone === true) return;

    // Page zoom or vertical scrollbars
    if(window.innerWidth !== document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
        // Sometimes one pixel too much. Compensate.
        if((window.innerWidth - 1) !== document.documentElement.clientWidth) return;

    }

    // Pad content if necessary.
    if(bPad === true && (document.documentElement.scrollHeight <= document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        // Extend body height to overflow and cause scrolling
        bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

        // Viewport height at fullscreen
        bodyTag.style.height = document.documentElement.clientWidth / screen.width * screen.height + 'px';

    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        // Already scrolled?
        if(window.pageYOffset !== 0) return;

        // Perform autoscroll
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);

        // Reset body height and scroll
        if(bodyTag !== undefined) bodyTag.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    }, 1000);

}

// Quick address bar hide on devices like the iPhone
//---------------------------------------------------
function quickHideAddressBar() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(window.pageYOffset !== 0) return;
        window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + 1);

    }, 1000);

}
```

Any clue on how to produce this "fullscreen landscape" effect on mobile browser (Safari/Chrome) ?